# Kivy create and acces ids of dynamically created buttons to change button text

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

So i am trying to build app to learn words in different languages. You create a folder(dict) with a word in one language as a key and as a value you put translated word.

Now ive made a PageLayout which creates as many buttons in pagelayout as many items i have in my dict and set as a text key()

py.file(This is class where i make buttons in pagelayout)

```
class CardGame(Screen):
    page = ObjectProperty(None)
    def cards(self):
        with open('data.json') as file:
            words = json.load(file)
            name = self.manager.get_screen('before_game').ids.spinner.text
            for key in words[name]:
                self.ids.page.add_widget(Button(text=str(key)))
```

kivy file

```
<CardGame>:
    page:page
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            Button:
                text:'back'
                on_press:root.back()
        PageLayout:
            border:100        <<<<<< Here it creates in this case 3 buttons
            id:page
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            Button:
                text:'left'
            Button:
                text:'right'


<RootWidget>:

    LoginScreen:
        name:'login_screen'
    SignUpScreen:
        name:'sign_up'

    LoginSuccesfull:
        name:'login_succesfull'
    ForgotPassword:
        name:'forgot_password'
    CardGame:
        name:'card_game'
        on_pre_enter:self.cards()
        on_leave:self.remove_buttons()
    NewWord:
        name:'new_word'
        on_enter:self.spiner()
    BeforeGame:
        name:'before_game'
        on_enter:self.spiner()
        on_leave:self.clear_spinner()
    Test:
        name:'test'
        on_pre_enter:self.testujemy()
```

dict:

```
{
    "animals": {
        "kot": "cat",
        "pies": "dog",
        "krowa": "cow"
    },
    "food": {
        "jajko": "egg",
        "szynka": "ham",
        "mleko": "milk"
    }
}
```

So in this scenario i choose which folder i want to open in Spinner and then after clicking button with game  it switches  to a Screen that will display PageLayout with all the buttons created with on_pre_enter in kv.file

How to create ids and then change button text by accesing theirs ids

Any help would be appreciated